# Get two adjacent images in a while loop PHP

Tags: php, css, foreach

I have a html code , when i convert into php some issues happended . Actually i need a `foreach` or `while loop` for the below div.

But all images are different (never mind the names of images, it can be any name).

```
<div class='img'>
   <img src='img/1.jpg'>
   <img src='img/2.jpg'>
 </div>
<div class='img'>
   <img src='img/3.jpg'>
   <img src='img/4.jpg'>
 </div>
//....more divs like this
```

Here my try

```
 $stmt=$db->query("Select * from photo");
  foreach ($stmt as $row)
  {

   ?>
   <div class='img'>
   <img src='img/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>'>
  <img src='img/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>'> // how to get this image diffent from above images 
   </div>
   <?php  }
```

Any experts?

Comment: img/1.jpg , img/2.jpg etc. these are individual records?I mean number is a ID from db?

Comment: all are from same table `photos` ,  of column `image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM photo");
$sth->execute();
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php $response = array(); ?>
<?php foreach ($data as $dataIndex => $dataValue): ?>
    <?php if ($i == 1): ?>
        <?php $response[] = '<img src="img' . $dataValue["image"] . '"/>'; ?>
        <?php $response[] = "</div>"; ?>
        <?php $i = 0; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php $response[] = "<div class='img'>"; ?>
        <?php $response[] = '<img src="img' . $dataValue["image"] . '"/>'; ?>
        <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php if(count($data)%2): ?>
  <?php $response[] = "</div>"; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo implode("", $response); ?>
```

**output:**

```
<div class="img">
  <img src="img1">
  <img src="img2">
</div>

<div class="img">
  <img src="img3">
  <img src="img4">
</div>

<div class="img">
  <img src="img5">
  <img src="img6">
</div>
```

Comment: Your code almost reached the output, but while dumping array i can see missing `</div>` in last..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$stmt` is an array, you can do this.

```
<?php
$count = 0
while(sizeof($stmt) > $count) {
    ?>
    <img src="<?php $stmt[$count]['image']?>"/>
    <?php
    $count++;
    ?>
    <img src="<?php $stmt[$count]['image']?>"/>
    <?php $count++; ?>
}
?>
```

Comment: can u pls make your code including query ...its showing some errors

Comment: Can you please specify the error and the framework you are using? Also a little heads up. Stackoverflow never encourages sharing a code that you can copy paste and get output.